# Only send form if all these conditions are matched (true)

Tags: php, validation, conditional-statements, registration, is-empty

So I have these inputs from my form `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `password`.

But I only want to complete the registration form and save it into my DB when all of these contain any info given by the user. I have this right now but it only shows an error if the password and/or password confirmation field do not match.

```
if( !empty ($_POST)){

    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation']) {
       $user = new User();
       $user->setFirstName($_POST['firstname']);
       $user->setLastName($_POST['lastname']);
       $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);
       $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
       $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);

    if($user->register()){
        $user->login();
    }

    else{
    $error_confirmation = true;
    // This gives error in the front end if both of the PW do no match each other
   }
}
```

I guess I am supposed to do something like this?

```
if( !empty ($_POST['firstname']) && !empty ($_POST['lastname']) && !empty ($_POST['username']) && !empty ($_POST['email']) && !empty ($_POST['password'])){
```

EDIT:
Okay I think I just figured it out by myself. The page doesn't send in the info but nor does it show the `$error_firstname=true;` messages?

```
if( !empty ($_POST['firstname']) && !empty ($_POST['lastname']) && !empty ($_POST['username']) && !empty ($_POST['email']) && !empty ($_POST['password'])){

    if( empty ($_POST['firstname'])){
        $error_firstname = true;
    }

    if( empty ($_POST['lastname'])){
        $error_lastname = true;
    }

    if( empty ($_POST['username'])){
        $error_username = true;
    }

    if( empty ($_POST['email'])){
        $error_email = true;
    }


    else if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation']) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setFirstName($_POST['firstname']);
        $user->setLastName($_POST['lastname']);
        $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);
        $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
        $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);

        if($user->register()){
            $user->login();
        }
    }
    else{
        $error_confirmation = true;
       // show pw confirmation error
    }
}
```

**Final edit: This does fix the issue.**

I fixed it with this and using `required` on the input html tags.
The first line checks if all the input is given then proceeds to the next `if` which checks if the pw that matches the pw confirmation and then saves into the DB

```
    if( !empty ($_POST['firstname']) && !empty ($_POST['lastname']) && !empty ($_POST['username']) && !empty ($_POST['email']) && !empty ($_POST['password'])){

    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation']) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setFirstName($_POST['firstname']);
        $user->setLastName($_POST['lastname']);
        $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);
        $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
        $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);

        if($user->register()){
            $user->login();
        }
    }
    else{
        $error_confirmation = true;
       // if no -> $error tonen
    }
}
```

Comment: if having an user with an empty value as firstname or email is not a valid user for you, then yes - validate your inputs. Enforce them as well inside your domain model.

Comment: `empty ($_POST['firstname'])` can never be true, you already check that it (and the others) are not empty.  You do need to check if `$_POST['password_confirmation']` is empty before comparing.  If you care about isolating which field is empty, don't bother with a multi-check condition; check each element one at a time.

Comment: I fixed it, check the edits

Comment: Confirmation could be empty; leading to Notice.

Comment: @mickmackusa oh I forgot to tell it in the post but the PW needs to be 8 characters long, so it can't be empty. if(strlen($password) < 8){
             throw  new Exception("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
         }

Comment: I wouldn't provide that feedback from serverside response.   I'd put a `pattern` attribute on the field so that the clientside stops submission on short passwords.  On the serverside, I'd check and give a general fail response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php conditional expressions short-circuit, so they will stop as soon as they reach a false evaluation.

```
if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST['password'])>=8 && !empty($_POST['password_confirmation']) && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation']) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setFirstName($_POST['firstname']);
    $user->setLastName($_POST['lastname']);
    $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);
    $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);

    if($user->register()){
        $user->login();
    }
} else {
    $error_confirmation = true;
   // if no -> $error tonen
}
```

As for cluing in the user about the password minimum, use a `pattern` attribute for clientside validation and a `placeholder` (or tooltip) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add 'required' attribute in the  tags of your HTML document.
eg:

But this attribute is supported only in HTML5 and not in versions before that.

For further reference please check:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: You should never trust client side validations.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called **Server Side** validation ,It is better to validate user input on Server Side because you can protect against the malicious users, who can easily bypass your Client Side scripting language and submit dangerous input to the server.

They another type of validation which i think you are missed ,is called **Client Side** validation .In the Client Side Validation you can provide a better user experience by responding quickly at the browser level. When you perform a Client Side Validation, all the user inputs validated in the user's browser itself. Client Side validation does not require a round trip to the server, so the network traffic which will help your server perform better.

You can do it on the browser side using script languages such as **JavaScript**, **JQuery** or **HTML5** attributes.Addtionaly , its have more powerfull functionality like validation whole form is currect before allow to user submit it .

Below some of tutorials of doing Server Side validation in PHP : -

[PHP Server Side Form Validation - W3schools](https://www.w3schools.in/php/form-validation/)

[Server Side Form Validations using PHP](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/02/server-side-form-validations-using-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !empty ($_POST['firstname']) && !empty ($_POST['lastname']) && !empty ($_POST['username']) && !empty ($_POST['email']) && !empty ($_POST['password'])){
```

This is what you should do because you are only checking only two field password and confirmation password. You have to check all the fields and then complete registration.